# Send Automatic Email once only from Shared Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that sends the contents of Sheet1 via email to a distribution list at a specific time in the day.
This is a shared Workbook, so multiple users have it open at the same time.

The code sends the email several times, either from the same user or from multiple users as "Sender" in the email. I assume because multiple users have the file open.

How can I send the email only once?

Sheet1 being sent in the email body:

```
Sub Email()

    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="1"

    Dim ChartName1 As String
    Dim dataTable As String
    Dim rng As Range

    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    'create a new message
    Set Message = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E11").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
  
    ChartName1 = Environ$("temp") & "\Chart1.gif"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Export _
    Filename:=ChartName1, FilterName:="GIF"
         
    With Message
        .Subject = " Files status " & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
     
        .HTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
          & "<p class=style2><span LANG=EN><font FACE=Calibri SIZE=2>" _
          & "Dear all,<br ><br >Please see below the Open Files status for today : " _
          & "<br><BR>"
                
        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & rangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>"
          
        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<html><body><img src=" & "'" & ChartName1 & "'><Br><Br><Br/></body></html>"
             
        '  .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><B>WEEKLY REPPORT:</B><br>" _
        '  & "<br>Best Regards,<br>Ed</font></span>"
            
        .To = "recipients here "
        .Cc = ""
                 
        .Display
        .Send
    End With
        
    Kill ChartName1
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="1"
End Sub
```

Function to send the Graph as picture:

```
Function rangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
    ' Working in Office 2000-2013
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    rangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    rangetoHTML = Replace(rangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Code to send the file every day at 09:05 AM, included in ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:05:00"), "Email"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can select one user, from where the macro should be executed, before calling the procedure you could have a check on the user, based on the following below:

```
If Application.UserName = "username" Then
```

Hope it might be useful.